# Dedicated CoreNLP Server Control Issues

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, stanford-nlp

**Question:** How can I confirm whether or not my "Dedicated Server" is running properly?

**Background:** I am working to get a 'Dedicated CoreNLP Server' running on a stand-alone Linux system. This system is a laptop running CentOS 7. This OS was chosen because the directions for a [Dedicated CoreNLP Server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) specifically state that they apply to CentOS.

I have followed the directions for the Dedicated CoreNLP Server step-by-step (outlined below):

1. Downloaded CoreNLP 3.7.0 from the Stanford CoreNLP website (not GitHub) and placed/extracted it into the [/opt/corenlp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKOqy.png) folder.
2. Installed `authbind` and created a user called 'nlp' with super user privileges and bind it to port 80

   `sudo mkdir -p /etc/authbind/byport/`

   `sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80`

   `sudo chown nlp:nlp /etc/authbind/byport/80`

   `sudo chmod 600 /etc/authbind/byport/80`
3. Copy the startup script from the source jar at path `edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/corenlp` to `/etc/init.d/corenlp`
4. Give executable permissions to the startup script: `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/corenlp`
5. Link the script to `/etc/rc.d/`: `ln -s /etc/init.d/corenlp /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/S75corenlp`

Completing these steps is supposed to allow me to run the command `sudo service corenlp start` in order to run the dedicated server. When I run this command in the terminal I get the output "CoreNLP server started" which **IS** consistent with the the start up script "corenlp". I then run the start command again and get this same response, which is **NOT** consistent with the start up script. From what I can tell, if the server is actually running and I try to start it again I should get the message "CoreNLP server is already running!" This leads me to believe that my server is not actually functioning as it is intended to.

**Is this command properly starting the server? How can I tell?**

Since the "proper" command was not functioning as I thought it should, I used the command `sudo systemctl *start* corenlp.service` and checked the service's status with `sudo systemctl *status* corenlp.service`. I am not sure if this is an appropriate way in which to start and stop a 'Dedicated CoreNLP Server' but I can control the service. I just do not know if I am actually starting and stopping my dedicated server.

**Can I use `systemctl` command to operate my `Dedicated CoreNLP Server`?**

Comment: @Gabor you seem to have knowledge and experience with CoreNLP. Could you provide me some insight as to whats I'm experiencing?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: What does `ps` tell you, and what do the logs say? The startup script was written a while ago, before we had the `/ready` endpoint for the server, so right now it always says the server was started even if it failed to start.

Comment: Not sure what I should expect to see with `ps`. I am a mechanical engineer and a little out of my element/still learning. If I only use `ps` with no arguments it prints two lines of output `4950 pts/5 00:00:00 ps` and `30134 pts/5 00:00:00 bash` I also used `ps -A to get a full list but I dont know what I'm looking for. Judging by how you said the script will say it started even if if failed to start, my server is failing to start. @Gabor

Comment: [nlp@localhost corenlp]$ ps -e
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:03 systemd
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
    7 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
    8 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
    9 ?        00:00:03 rcu_sched
   10 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
   11 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/1
   12 ?        00:00:00 migration/1
   13 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/1
   15 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0H
   16 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/2
   17 ?        00:00:00 migration/2
   18 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/2

Comment: So, mostly the `ps` experiment is just to confirm that corenlp isn't running. For example, `ps aux | grep java` will only return one process if no java processes are running -- the ps process itself. The next step is to look at the logs, which I believe will be in `/opt/corenlp` by default, or whatever `CORENLP_DIR` is set to in the script. As an aside, this is also the directory you should have the unzipped CoreNLP distribution in for the startup script to work.

Comment: I did unzip the CoreNLP distribution into the /opt/corenlp and I see two log files. `stderr.log` and `stdout.log`; `stderr.log` contains this "bash: /usr/local/bin/authbind: No such file or directory" and `stdout.log` is empty. I had noticed that in the start up script it calls "su "$SERVER_USER" -c "/usr/local/bin/authbind --deep java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CORENLP_DIR" -cp "$CLASSPATH" -mx15g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 80"" and I looked for the /usr/local/bin/authbind folder and also noticed it did not exist. @Gabor

Comment: Ah, that seems fixable -- it looks like you need to install `authbind`. Perhaps with [this](https://aaronsilber.me/2016/04/24/install-authbind-on-centos-7-x86_64-download-the-rpm/)? Alternately, maybe authbind is somewhere else on your machine. You can try `whereis authbind` or `which authbind` and see if it turns up anything.

Comment: I definitely installed authbind. I acutally did it with the link you referenced above. I ran the command `where is authbind` and got the following output: authbind: /usr/bin/authbind /usr/lib64/authbind /etc/authbind /usr/share/man/man1/authbind.1.gz so it is not located in /usr/local/bin/ -- should I change the start up script to reflect /usr/bin/authbind?

Comment: I attempted to change the start up script and now I have output in my `stderr.log` file. The server failed to boot up completely. The error is as follows, "ERROR Could not start liveness server. This will probably result in very bad things happening soon. - java.net.BindException: Address already in use" I assume this means port 80 is already in use. I will try to turn off my wifi and see if that helps. @Gabor

Comment: It continued after the error I reported in my above comment. Though it shut down the server after having my permissions denied. "[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting Server...java.net.SocketException: Permission denied" @Gabor sorry for overloading you with comments. your help is VERY VERY much appreciated.

Comment: @Gabor I got it up and running!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! If you would like to throw up an answer to the 'original' question I will accept it as the correct answer so you get your reputation points. We have been running in circles for 2 weeks trying to get this to work and your help was HUGE in getting it to work. I know it wasnt a lot but it was very VERY helpful. You made my day. Thank you.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad I was helpful :). Really, someday I should make the startup script more robust / production ready.

Comment: Hopefully this post will be sufficient until you get the time to make it more production ready @Gabor Feel free to up vote this Question. Help a mechanical engineer new to the software game get some Stack Overflow credibility.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the comments below the originally posted question. This was the back and forth between @GaborAngeli and myself which lead my question/problem being solved.

The two critical steps I took in order to get my instantiation of the CoreNLP server running locally on my machine after following all the directions on how to setup a dedicated server, which are outlined on Stanford CoreNLP's webpage, are as follows:

1. Made two modifications to the "corenlp" start-up script. (1) added sudo to the beginning because the user "nlp" needs permissions to certain files on the system (2) changed the first folder path from /usr/local/bin/authbind to /usr/bin/authbind. `authbind` installation must've changed since the start up script was written.

   `nohup su "$SERVER_USER" -c "sudo /usr/bin/authbind --deep java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir_"$CORENLP_DIR" -cp "$CLASSPATH" -mx15g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 80"`
2. If you were to attempt to start the server with the change above you would not successfully run server because sudo usage requires a password input. In order to allow sudo privileges without a required password entry you need to edit the sudoers file (I did this under the root user b/c you need permissions to change or even view this document). my sudoers file was located in /etc. There is a part that says `## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands` and below that is a section that says `##Same thing without a password`. You just need to remove the comment mark (#) form in front of the next line which says `%wheel     ALL+(ALL)     NOPASSWD:  ALL`. Save this file. **BE CAREFUL IN EDITING THIS FILE AS IT MAY CAUSE SERIOUS ISSUES. MAKE ONLY THE NECESSARY CHANGE OUTLINED ABOVE**

Those two steps allowed me to successfully run my dedicated server. My system runs on CentOS 7.

**HELPFUL TIP:** From my discussion with @GaborAngeli I learned that within the 'corenlp' folder (/opt/corenlp if you followed the directions correctly) you can open the `stderr.log` file to help you in trouble shooting your server. This outputs what you would see if you were to run the server in the command window. If there is an error it is output here too, which is extremely helpful.