# Stanford coreNLP Dedicated server not running

Tags: http, centos, centos7, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run a dedicated coreNLP server using a CentOS7 server hosted on Linode.com. I have followed all the instructions from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#dedicated-server and then read and consequently updated my scripts and user permissions using this post: [Dedicated CoreNLP Server Control Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744429/dedicated-corenlp-server-control-issues) but unfortunately I still can't connect to the service through any means. Every time it says 'connection refused' if I try and connect through localhost, or load the ip in my browser, or try and connect through he android app I am attempting to develop.

Prior to starting the coreNLP service I disabled all firewalls using iptables scripts and disabling firewalld. I am running as user nlp on port 80. I tried to icmp ping the server from another machine which worked fine.

I changed access permissions in the /opt/corenlp directory although I'm not sure that made a difference. Here is my terminal output. I used systemctl although the sudo service command also produced the same thing.

```
sudo systemctl start corenlp
[nlp@aqghost /]$ sudo systemctl status corenlp -l
● corenlp.service - (null)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/corenlp; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-06-17 13:53:59 BST; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9413 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/corenlp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 17 13:53:59 aqghost systemd[1]: Starting (null)...
Jun 17 13:53:59 aqghost corenlp[9413]: CoreNLP server is already running!
Jun 17 13:53:59 aqghost corenlp[9413]: If you are sure this is a mistake, delete the file:
Jun 17 13:53:59 aqghost corenlp[9413]: /opt/corenlp/corenlp.shutdown
Jun 17 13:53:59 aqghost systemd[1]: Started (null).
[nlp@aqghost /]$ sudo systemctl start corenlp
[nlp@aqghost /]$ sudo systemctl status
● aqghost
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Thu 2021-06-17 10:35:33 BST; 3h 18min ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─1 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserializ
           ├─user.slice
           │ ├─user-0.slice
           │ │ └─session-25.scope
           │ │   ├─9263 sshd: root@pts/1
           │ │   └─9267 -bash
           │ └─user-1000.slice
           │   └─session-21.scope
           │     ├─8745 sshd: nlp [priv]
           │     ├─8751 sshd: nlp@pts/0
           │     ├─8752 -bash
           │     ├─9426 sudo systemctl status
           │     ├─9428 systemctl status
           │     └─9429 less
           └─system.slice
             ├─tuned.service
             │ └─799 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
             ├─rsyslog.service
             │ └─797 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
             ├─sshd.service
             │ └─796 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
             ├─crond.service
             │ └─577 /usr/sbin/crond -n
             ├─systemd-logind.service
             │ └─573 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
             ├─NetworkManager.service
             │ └─572 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
             ├─dbus.service
             │ └─564 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofor
             ├─polkit.service
             │ └─563 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
             ├─irqbalance.service
             │ └─559 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
             ├─auditd.service
             │ └─512 /sbin/auditd
             ├─systemd-udevd.service
             │ └─430 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
             ├─system-serial\x2dgetty.slice
             │ └─serial-getty@ttyS0.service
             │   └─583 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 ttyS0 vt220
             ├─system-getty.slice
             │ └─getty@tty1.service
             │   └─584 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
             └─systemd-journald.service
               └─399 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald

[nlp@aqghost /]$ sudo ps aux | grep java
nlp       9431  0.0  0.0 112812   964 pts/0    S+   13:54   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

(Note. I seemed to make the server work ONCE, for about 20 seconds. I'm not sure how and why but I could connect via my app that i'm dveloping and via localhost on the same server. This is also what showed in my stderr.log and stdout.log: (ignore the fact that theres four outputs here, i'm still leanring JSON formatting and i think i sent the same thing))

```
 sudo cat /opt/corenlp/stdout.log
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
{"inputFormat":"text","data":"I am going to the shops.","annotators":"tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref","outputFormat":"json"}
{"inputFormat":"text","data":"I am going to the shops.","annotators":"tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref","outputFormat":"json"}
{"inputFormat":"text","data":"I am going to the shops.","annotators":"tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref","outputFormat":"json"}
{"inputFormat":"text","data":"I am going to the shops.","annotators":"tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref","outputFormat":"json"}



$ sudo cat /opt/corenlp/stderr.log
[main] INFO CoreNLP - --- StanfordCoreNLPServer#main() called ---
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Server default properties:
                        (Note: unspecified annotator properties are English defaults)
                        inputFormat = text
                        outputFormat = json
                        prettyPrint = false
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Threads: 4
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting server...
[main] INFO CoreNLP - StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0.0.0.0:80
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO CoreNLP - [/127.0.0.1:60614] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.0 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO CoreNLP - [/128.243.2.12:48192] API call w/annotators <unknown>
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties ... found.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.2 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.8 sec].
[pool-1-thread-2] INFO CoreNLP - [/128.243.2.12:48196] API call w/annotators <unknown>
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.1 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl - Using following SUTime rules: edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt,edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt,edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - ner.fine.regexner: Read 580705 unique entries out of 581864 from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/gazetteers/regexner_caseless.tab, 0 TokensRegex patterns.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - ner.fine.regexner: Read 4867 unique entries out of 4867 from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/gazetteers/regexner_cased.tab, 0 TokensRegex patterns.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - ner.fine.regexner: Read 585572 unique entries from 2 files
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO CoreNLP - [/128.243.2.12:48228] API call w/annotators <unknown>
[pool-1-thread-4] INFO CoreNLP - [/128.243.2.12:48230] API call w/annotators <unknown>
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NERCombinerAnnotator - numeric classifiers: true; SUTime: true [no docDate]; fine grained: true
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser - Loading depparse model: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... Time elapsed: 67.3 sec
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.Classifier - PreComputed 20000 vectors, elapsed Time: 1.244 sec
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser - Initializing dependency parser ... done [68.6 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator coref
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.SimpleLinearClassifier - Loading coref model edu/stanford/nlp/models/coref/statistical/ranking_model.ser.gz ... done [1.5 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CorefMentionAnnotator - Using mention detector type: dependency
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator kbp
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.KBPAnnotator - Loading KBP classifier from: edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/tac-re-lr.ser.gz
Killed
```

Here is my service script modified according to the linked post:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# A script to start/stop the CoreNLP server on port 80, made
# in particular for the configuration running at corenlp.run.
# This script should be placed into:
#
#   /etc/init.d/corenlp
#
# To run it at startup, link to the script using:
#
#   ln -s /etc/init.d/conenlp /etc/rc.2/S75corenlp
#
# Usage:
#
#    service corenlp [start|stop]
#    ./corenlp [start|stop]
#

#
# Set this to the username you would like to use to run the server.
# Make sure that this user can authbind to port 80!
#
SERVER_USER="nlp"
CORENLP_DIR="/opt/corenlp"


do_start()
{
  if [ -e "$CORENLP_DIR/corenlp.shutdown" ]; then
    echo "CoreNLP server is already running!"
    echo "If you are sure this is a mistake, delete the file:"
    echo "$CORENLP_DIR/corenlp.shutdown"
  else
    export CLASSPATH=""
    for JAR in `find "$CORENLP_DIR" -name "*.jar"`; do
      CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JAR"
    done
    nohup su nlp -c "sudo /usr/bin/authbind --deep java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/corenlp -cp "$CLASSPATH" -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=100 -mx20g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 80" \
      > "$CORENLP_DIR/stdout.log" 2> "$CORENLP_DIR/stderr.log" &
    echo "CoreNLP server started."
  fi
}

do_stop()
{
  if [ ! -e "$CORENLP_DIR/corenlp.shutdown" ]; then
    echo "CoreNLP server is not running"
  else
    KEY=`cat "$CORENLP_DIR/corenlp.shutdown"`
    curl "localhost/shutdown?key=$KEY"
    echo "CoreNLP server stopped"
  fi
}

do_restart()
{
  do_stop
  sleep 3
  do_start
}

case $1 in
start) do_start
;;
stop) do_stop
;;
restart) do_restart
;;
esac
```

Sorry for all the info. I am new to linux and running a server and initialising scripts so please be easy on me.

Comment: Try to delete the file: `/opt/corenlp/corenlp.shutdown` and run `sudo systemctl start corenlp` again

Comment: @rzlvmp I deleted it and ran the service and it works!!!! Thank you so much!!!!! How did deleting that affect it may I ask?

Comment: I just read `Jun 17 13:53:59 aqghost corenlp[9413]: If you are sure this is a mistake, delete the file:` in your logs and made suggestion